# Is there any position I can get gps signal on Boeing 787?

Tags: boeing-787

As an aviation enthusiast, I use some apps like garmin pilot to capture gps signal on planes to track plane routes.

But I found that I can't get any gps signal on 787. I guess the reason is the material of the electronic dimming system. Is there any position in the cabin to get a better gps signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fuselage of the 787 is entirely made from carbon laminate as can be seen in this picture (taken from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-CFRP-parts-of-dreamliner-Boeing-787-1_fig1_225022367)):
[image: The CFRP parts of dreamliner Boeing 787]

Cabon fiber blocks GPS and other radio signals pretty well. So unfortunately no, there is no part of the fuselage which offers better GPS reception. You could try to push the antenna agains the window, perhaps the GPS-Tracker has better luck picking up a signal there...

Comment: And to make matters worse, there's a copper mesh embedded in the composite for lightning protection.

Comment: @u_flow I tried to put antenna against the windows. But no luck